# how to match in perl using \d?

Tags: perl, matching

Just a stupid question - what is the meaning of d in the following code. What role is it playing in it?

```
$str = 'Telephone: 040-27614396';
$str =~ m/Telephone:\s*(\d{3}-\d{8})$/;
```

Please also tell the meaning of these kind of stuff

```
if (/^\#/)
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: The expression is checking if the string variable `$str` matches the regular expression `m/Telephone:\s*(\d{3}-\d{8})$/`.  Look here for more details on Perl expression matching: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expressions.htm

Answer (score 0):

The expression is checking if the string variable `$str` matches the regular expression `/Telephone:\s*(\d{3}-\d{8})$/`.

Look here for more details on Perl expression matching:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expressions.htm

The link also discusses:

- \d:    Matches digits. Equivalent to [0-9].
- ^:  Matches beginning of line.
- \: "escapes" the following character: "#" means it will treat "#" as "#" ... instead of trying to interpret it as a metacharacter.

There are many tutorials about "regular expressions" on the web that can help explain in more depth.